Translation of 近乎是要套
https://www.rfa.org/mandarin/pinglun/jujiaoweiwuer/ylxt-04302024130500.html has
过套近乎是要套 user suggestion using online dictionaries esp. BKRS:to befriend (be friendly to) (s.o.) in order to get (ferret out) (s.th.), in the present case 她的话 could mean "information")

tried to cut 过, which does not belong there, but did not succeed

Can you please put more effort into this question? It's written like a stream-of-consciousness, with no sentence demarcation and thus unclear details of who is asking what, who is presenting what information, ...

The original sentence is "两位维吾尔警察实际是通过套近乎是要套她的话。"
I think it would be easier to understand/translate if modified as "两位维吾尔警察 实际是 通过"套近乎" 去套她的话"

The phrase 套近乎 originally meant "Use cordial words or gifts to build closer relationships". Here, it means the police used homogeneity as bait to get closer to her.

The 套 in bold is a verb that means "cheat/trick to get something out".


The translation is:

Actually, these two Uyghur police were to cheat/trick the word out of her by building a closer relationship with her.


两位维吾尔警察: 2 Uighur police agents
实际: actually, really
通过套近乎: by means of ingratiating themselves
套话: polite talk
套她的话: trick her into telling (them something)
两位维吾尔警察实际是通过套近乎是要套她的话.
Two Uighur police agents are trying to get the truth from her by ingratiating themselves with her.
Ingratiating is better than torture!

The multiple 套 probably confused you.
It has to be parsed this way : 通过套近乎，(是)要套她的话.
通過 = via; by; by means of; through
套近乎 = worm one's way into being friends with sb. (usually
derogatory)
套話 = to coax a secret from (or out of) someone; to trick someone into telling the truth
